# Resizing the WIDTH of UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, ios, datepicker, uidatepicker

Is it possible to CHANGE the WIDTH of the UIDatePicker ?

Im trying to do this programmatically, not via storyboards...iOS 6.1

Thanks.

Miles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's something you would change by setting the `frame` property.

For example, if you wanted to increase the width of your `datePicker` object by *50 points*:

```
CGRect frame = self.datePicker.frame;
frame.size.width += 50;
[self.datePicker setFrame: frame];
```

Comment: Im using the following code.

`UIDatePicker *timePick;
timePick = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 0, 0)];
timePick.datePickerMode =UIDatePickerModeTime;

[viewCon.view addSubview:timePick];`

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the frame when you create picker, does not work.

```
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 300)];
```

You should create before and then change frame:

```
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
CGRect frame = picker.frame;
frame.size.width = 300;
...
[picker setFrame:frame];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the frame when you create picker, does not work.

```
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.width - 216, self.view.frame.size.width,216)];
```

you can try

```
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
CGRect frame = picker.frame;
frame.origin.x  = (self.frame.size.width - 320)/2;
frame.size.width = self.frame.size.width - (picker.frame.origin.x * 2);
[picker setFrame:frame];
```